# MS sql server-Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Anyone can help me to find the error in this code, when I execute it says

> "Procedure or function 'dep_cnt' expects parameter '@cnt', which was not supplied."

I want to count number of departments in colombo.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dep_cnt
 @dep_loc varchar(10),
 @cnt int
AS
SELECT @Cnt = count(*) FROM Department WHERE Dept_Loc = @dep_loc
```

And

```
EXEC dep_cnt @dep_loc = 'colombo'
```

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear

Comment: You need to pass *in* `@cnt` but its pointless as its immediately overwritten? To *return* a value use `return` or an `output` paramater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either pass a `@cnt` parameter with a value to your stored procedure call, or set a default of `NULL` to the `@cnt` parameter inside the procedure definition, like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dep_cnt 
    @dep_loc varchar(10)
  , @cnt int = NULL 
AS 
    SELECT @Cnt = count(*) 
    FROM Department 
    WHERE Dept_Loc = @dep_loc

EXEC dep_cnt @dep_loc = 'colombo'
```

Although I don't see much value in this, maybe you're looking for `@cnt` as an output / returned value?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dep_cnt 
    @dep_loc varchar(10)
  , @cnt int OUTPUT
AS 
    SELECT @Cnt = count(*) 
    FROM Department 
    WHERE Dept_Loc = @dep_loc

DECLARE @cntResult int    

EXEC dep_cnt @dep_loc = 'colombo', @cnt = @cntResult OUTPUT
```

You can find more info here about [returning data from a stored procedure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: It should be `@cnt int = NULL` not `@cnt int NULL` this will throw and error.